# chartjs show dot point on hover over line chart

Tags: javascript, jquery, chart.js

I am using Chartjs v.1.0.2 and trying to set a point dot only to appear on hover over chart. After it it should be removed. I have managed to show it, by changing the object value, but it is not fluid motion and it doesn't show point always. This also doesn't hide it on hover out.
How can it be fluid and hide when mouse is not over?

```
window.onload = function(){

        var ctx = $("#chart1").get(0).getContext("2d");
                var chart1 = new Chart(ctx).Line(data1, options);


                $("#chart1").hover(function(e) {
                    var activeBars = chart1.getPointsAtEvent(e); 
                    activeBars[0].display = true;
//                    console.log(activeBars[0]);
                    chart1.update();
                 });

    };

    var data1 = {
            labels: ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July"],
            datasets: [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor: "rgba(95,186,88,0.7)",
                    strokeColor: "rgba(95,186,88,1)",
                    pointColor: "rgba(95,186,88,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill: "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(220,220,220,1)",
                    data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40]
                }
            ]
    };



var options = {
    responsive: true,
    bezierCurve : false,
    scaleShowLabels: false,
    scaleFontSize: 0,
    pointDot : false,
    scaleBeginAtZero: true,
    scaleShowHorizontalLines: false,
    scaleShowVerticalLines: true,
    scaleGridLineColor : "rgba(232,232,232)",
    showTooltips: true,

    customTooltips: function (tooltip) {
        var tooltipEl = $('#chartjs-tooltip');

        if (!tooltip) {
            tooltipEl.css({
                opacity: 0
            });
            return;
        }

        tooltipEl.removeClass('above below');
        tooltipEl.addClass(tooltip.yAlign);

        // split out the label and value and make your own tooltip here
        var parts = tooltip.text.split(":");
        var innerHtml = '<span>' + parts[0].trim() + '</span> : <span><b>' + parts[1].trim() + '</b></span>';
        tooltipEl.html(innerHtml);

        tooltipEl.css({
            opacity: 1,
            left: tooltip.chart.canvas.offsetLeft + tooltip.x + 'px',
            top: tooltip.chart.canvas.offsetTop + tooltip.y + 'px',
            fontFamily: tooltip.fontFamily,
            fontSize: tooltip.fontSize,
            fontStyle: tooltip.fontStyle,
        });
    }

};
```

simplified [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8aehhusx/2/)

Answer (score 14):

Tested with Chart.js v2.6.0

Global setting will do the trick:

```
Chart.defaults.global.hover.intersect = false;
```

Or directly in chart config:

```
options: {
  hover: {
    intersect: false;
  }
}
```

And point settings for dataset.

- initial color of the point should be transparent
- hover color must be set to the desired color

e.g.

```
datasets: [{
  label: 'My First dataset',
  borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
  backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
  data: [10, 30, 46, 2, 8, 50, 0],
  fill: false,
  pointBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
  pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
  pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
  pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'}],...
```

```js
window.onload = function() {
  const mode = 'index';
  const intersect = false;
  const config = {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July'],
      datasets: [{
        label: 'My First dataset',
        borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        data: [10, 30, 46, 2, 8, 50, 0],
        fill: false,
        pointBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
        pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
      }, {
        label: 'My Second dataset',
        borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        backgroundColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        data: [7, 49, 46, 13, 25, 30, 22],
        fill: false,
        pointBorderColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        pointBackgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
        pointHoverBackgroundColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
      }]
    },
    options: {
      responsive: true,
      title: {
        display: true,
        text: 'Mode: index, intersect = false'
      },
      tooltips: {
        mode: 'index',
        intersect: intersect,
      },
      hover: {
        mode: mode,
        intersect: intersect
      },
    }
  };
  const ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
  const chart = new Chart(ctx, config);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.6.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: can we show the point anywhere on the graph when mouse is hovered ?

Answer (score 5):

Edit: The following solution is for Chart.js v1.0.2 (the latest version at the time this solution was proposed). Please refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47336050/2463246) which provides a solution for Chart.js v2.x.x.

---

I ran into a similar situation a while back and resolved this by making the default point dot "invisible" as follows:

- setting **pointDotRadius** to 1
- setting **pointStrokeColor** to white with the alpha set to 0

The two steps above make the default point dot very small, this, in combination with the transparent point stroke, makes the default point dot invisible. Now if we make the **pointDotStrokeWidth** large enough, we can achieve the desired hover effect. i.e.

- set **pointDotStrokeWidth** to a larger value (I used 8)
- set the desired values for **pointColor**, **pointHighlightFill**, **pointHighlightStroke**

> [Note: the same effect can be achieved by making **pointColor**
> transparent but if you are plotting multiple datasets, then the
> tooltip wouldn't show the corresponding line color next to the data
> value.]

Example below (or you can checkout this [Fiddle: ChartJS - Show Points on Hover](https://jsfiddle.net/schaazzz/vkjzpoaf/)):

```js
var data = {
  labels: ["Point0", "Point1", "Point2", "Point3", "Point4"],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "My Chart",
      fillColor: "rgba(87, 167, 134, 0.2)",
      strokeColor: "rgba(87, 167, 134, 1)",
      pointColor: "rgba(87, 167, 134, 1)",
      pointStrokeColor: "rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)",
      pointHighlightFill: "rgba(87, 167, 134, 0.7)",
      pointHighlightStroke: "rgba(87, 167, 134, 1)",
      data: [5, 39, 109, 19, 149]
    }
  ]
};
var ctx = document.getElementById("my_chart").getContext("2d");
myChart = new Chart(ctx).Line(data, {
  responsive : true,
  bezierCurve: false,
  datasetFill: true,
  pointDotRadius: 1,
  pointDotStrokeWidth: 8,
  pointHitDetectionRadius: 20,
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="my_chart"></canvas>
```

Comment: can we show the point anywhere on the graph when mouse is hovered ?

Comment: In my example, the point is shown only on the data points. In any case, my solution is more than 3 years old (Chart.js 1.0.2), the newer versions have had most APIs redesigned and contain a lot of convenience features.

Comment: I couldnt find any solution. can you please help me to show random circles on the graph

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#chart1").mouseover(function(e) {
    chart1.datasets[0].points[0].display = true;
    chart1.update();
 });
$("#chart1").mouseout(function(e) {
    chart1.datasets[0].points[0].display = false;
    chart1.update();
 });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but this only shows point dot on first place in graph. Though it does show it on/off fast which i am looking for

Answer (score 1):

This is a six years old question but I think in 2022 we can use [ChartJS version 4.0.1](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/4.0.1/).

ChartJS supports [interactions](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/interactions.html) behavior, and they can be configured via `interaction`, `hover` or `tooltips` settings on the chart configuration.

For this we will use the `hover` setting and select the `index` mode. This mode finds an item at the same index. If the `intersect` setting is `false` the nearest item, in the `x` direction, is used to determine the index.

Here is a working snippet

```js
const data = {
  labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
  datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      borderWidth: 1
    },
    {
      label: '# of Points',
      data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
      borderWidth: 1
    }
  ]
}
const options = {
  maintainAspectRatio: false,
  elements: {
    point: {
      hoverRadius: 6,
    },
  },
  hover: {
    mode: 'index',
    intersect: false,
  },
}
  
const config = {
  type: 'line',
  data,
  options,
}

const $chart = document.getElementById('chart')
const chart = new Chart($chart, config)
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" style="width: 98vw; height: 180px">
  <canvas id="chart"></canvas>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/chart.js@4.0.1/dist/chart.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `mouseover` and `mouseout` as shown below. Similarly you can also use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` methods to handle events.

```
$("#chart1").mouseover(function(e) {
                var activeBars = chart1.getPointsAtEvent(e); 
                activeBars[0].display = true;
                chart1.update();
             });

$("#chart1").mouseout(function(e) {
                var activeBars = chart1.getPointsAtEvent(e); 
                activeBars[0].display = false;
                chart1.update();
             });
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this does help in removing the dot on mouseout but not always, and showing the dot is not always working well. You can see the fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/8aehhusx/4/